# Sorting a list of String arrays

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, comparator

I am receiving a list of String array

```
String[] sa1 = {"120", "John" , "30" , "[\"science\",\"arts\"]"};
String[] sa2 = {"20", "Michael" , "29" , "[\"commerce\",\"engineering\"]"};
String[] sa3 = {"20", "Andrew" , "31" , "[\"science\",\"engineering\"]"};
```

The List that i receive, contains these type of arrays.
The current approach I am using for sorting is:

```
Collections.sort(nameL, new Comparator<String[]>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {


            return Arrays.toString(o1).compareTo(Arrays.toString(o2));
        }
    });
```

But this sorts on the basis of Ascii characters as array is of type string.
**The problem is I don't know the position in which the integers will come**

It can be:

```
sa1 = {"John", "120" , "30" , "[\"science\",\"arts\"]"};
```

**but if sa1 is like this then sa2 and sa3 will also have integers at same position**.

**AIM is to sort according to first, if same then second and so on:**

**Desired output**:

```
{"20", "Andrew" , "31" , "[\"science\",\"engineering\"]"}
{"20", "Michael" , "29" , "[\"commerce\",\"engineering\"]"},
{"120", "John" , "30" , "[\"science\",\"arts\"]"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got you properly you need a multicriteria sort, the trick with your comparator is that elememts at index 0 are strings representing integers, so it would be better to parse those as ints

```
    List<String[]> nameL = Arrays.asList(sa1, sa2, sa3);
    Collections.sort(nameL, (o1, o2) -> {
        if (o1[0].equals(o2[0])) {
            if (o1[1].equals(o2[1])) {

                return o1[2].compareTo(o2[2]);

            } else {
                return o1[1].compareTo(o2[1]);
            }
        } else {
            return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1[0]), Integer.parseInt(o2[0]));
        }
    });
    for (String[] strings : nameL) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
    }
```

Comment: The position of strings representing integers is not known, they can be at any position

Comment: @QO23 are all other strings not numeric only?

Comment: I mean if  `sa1 = {"20", "Andrew" , "31", "[\"science\",\"engineering\"]"` then all the other strings will be of same format, if `sa1 = {"John", "120" , "30" , "[\"science\",\"arts\"]"}`  has the string integers at second position then all other strings will have same format
The position of string integer within string array is unknown

Comment: i got your point, since the size of string array is not known, so i modified it slightly and called a recursive function that takes the string arays and next comparison index from inside the if else something like 

`compareInt = o1[index].compareTo(o2[index]);
   if(compareInt == 0){
    index = index + 1;
    compareInt = sortRecursive(o1, o2, index);
   }`
This solved my issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
Comparator<String[]> comparator = Comparator.comparing(array -> {
                                      try {
                                          return Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
                                      } catch (Exception ex) {
                                          return array[0];
                                      }
                                  });

// if all arrays have equal first elements, use the next elements to sort on
String[] firstArray = yourListOfArrays.get(0);
// i starts at 1 because we've used 0 already to create the comparator
for (int i = 1; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    // i is changing on each iteration, so Java will not allow i
    // to be used inside a lamda
    int index = i;
    comparator.thenComparing(array -> try {
                                          return Integer.parseInt(array[index]);
                                       } catch (Exception ex) {
                                          return array[index];
                             });
}

yourListOfArrays.sort(comparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.
First find out where your Integer is located. Referring to this you know where your String is. Then first sort by String and afterwards by Integer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] sa1 = {"John", "120", "30", "[\"science\",\"arts\"]"};
    String[] sa2 = {"Michael", "20", "29", "[\"commerce\",\"engineering\"]"};
    String[] sa3 = {"Andrew", "20", "31", "[\"science\",\"engineering\"]"};
    String[] sa4 = {"Peter", "2020", "31", "[\"science\",\"engineering\"]"};
    String[] sa5 = {"Bob", "99", "31", "[\"science\",\"engineering\"]"};
    String[] sa6 = {"Frank", "333", "31", "[\"science\",\"engineering\"]"};

    List<String[]> nameL = new ArrayList<>();
    nameL.add(sa1);
    nameL.add(sa2);
    nameL.add(sa3);
    nameL.add(sa4);
    nameL.add(sa5);
    nameL.add(sa6);

    int positionInteger = 0;
    int positionString = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sa1.length; i++) {
        if (isNumeric(sa1[i])) {
            positionInteger = i;
            if(i == 0){
                positionString = 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }


    final int pInteger = positionInteger;
    final int pString = positionString;

    Collections.sort(nameL, new Comparator<String[]>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            return o1[pString].compareTo(o2[pString]);
        }
    });


    Collections.sort(nameL, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {

            if(Integer.parseInt(o1[pInteger]) - Integer.parseInt(o2[pInteger]) == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if(Integer.parseInt(o1[pInteger]) - Integer.parseInt(o2[pInteger]) > 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            if(Integer.parseInt(o1[pInteger]) - Integer.parseInt(o2[pInteger]) < 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    });

    for (String[] str : nameL) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
    }
}

private static boolean isNumeric(String value)
{
    boolean isNumeric = false;

    try
    {
        int probe = Integer.parseInt(value);
        isNumeric = true;

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    return isNumeric;
}
```